# Perl appending text to new line

Tags: perl

Trying to append a new user on a new line into a text file but all my lines are getting modified.

This is my text file:

Joe W,john,asdf

Arnold K,bnads,1234

Marissa G,mglav,pass

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(FILE, "+<test.txt") or die "Couldn't open file $!";

        if ($user eq $fields[1]) {
                print "Taken";

        elsif ($user ne $fields[1]) {
                print FILE "$user";
        }


}

close(FILE);
```

When I run this my text file changes to

Joe W,john,asdf

test K,bnads,1234

test G,mglav,pass

test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding user to end of file, only if it is not already taken,

```
my $taken = 0;
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
        chomp $line;

        # splits each line into three fields
        my @fields = split "," , $line;

        if ($user eq $fields[1]) {
                print "Username is taken.\n";
                $taken = 1;
                last;
        }

}

if (!$taken) {
   print FILE "$user\n";
}
```

Comment: @user2980566 it skips/exits rest of the loop, in this case stops reading the file.

Comment: I really don't like your solution: it breaks many common *best practice* rules.

Comment: @Borodin could you refer to two or three of them (best practices rules)? Answer is based on existing OP question, so it _illustrates_ where did it go wrong, and what could be possible solution.